# Question about exponential of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, analysis, tensor-products

Let $W$ be a skew-symmetric second order tensor, i.e., a linear map from a vector space $V\to V$ for which $W^T=-W$, where the transpose of a tensor is defined as the unique tensor with the property that
$$(Wu)\cdot v=u\cdot (W^Tv) \; \text{for all} \; u,v\in V.$$

Now the exponential function on second-order tensors is a mapping defined by
$$\exp S= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!} S^j.$$

I want to prove that if $W$ is a skew symmetric second order tensor then $\exp W$ is a rotation tensor, i.e.
$$(\exp W)^T (\exp W)=I \; \text{and} \; \det(\exp W)=1.$$

I am not able to find a proof to this theorem.

First, I know we should have $\exp(W^T)=(\exp W)^T$, but how can I prove this from the definition, that is, how can I show that $(\exp W)u \cdot v = u \cdot (\exp W^T)v$ for all $u,v \in V$?

Next, from the definition of the exponential of a linear map in terms of infinite sum, how can I show that $\exp(W^T) \exp(W)=I?$

And finally, how do we show that the determinant of the exponential is equal to $1$? To find the determinant, we need to find the matrix representation of the exponential of a linear map, but how do we find this? I suppose it must be $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!} A^j$ where $A$ is the matrix representation of $W$, and then using that skew-symmetric matrices have diagonals $0$ I can get the determinant of the exponential equal to $1$, but I don't know how to show that the matrix representation of the exponential of a linear map is the exponential of its matrix representation.

I would greatly appreciate some help with these questions.

Comment: Can you not use the distributive property to show that 1) is valid for any sun of two tensors and conclude from there to the exponential?

Comment: What does skew-symmetry get you?

Comment: $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ so $(e^W)^T = e^{(W^T)}$.

Comment: Another approach for the determinant: observe that $W$ is path connected to zero   (which is skew symmetric) via $\tau \cdot W$ for $\tau \in [0,1]$ so $\exp\big(\tau \cdot W\big)$ shows $\exp\big(W\big)$ is in the same component as the identity matrix -- and the determinant is a continuous, integer valued function for orthogonal maps, hence constant on a component.

Comment: @infinitezero Which distributive property do you mean?

Comment: @TedShifrin Where do I use the skew-symmetry for $(\exp W)^T I(\exp W)=I$?

Comment: @CyclotomicField My concern is how I can apply the transpose over an infinite sum. Why is this allowed?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician an infinite sum is the limit of finite sums. Since each finite sum is composed of the transposes you can use it for the infinite sums. From there you'll need to use skew-symmetry to eliminate the transposes. You should see a simple pattern after the first few terms. In order to prove that new series is the identity you can show that they multiply to the identity. You shouldn't have to calculate this directly, just use that $e^xe^{-x}=1$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I know the infinite sum converges but I don't know how I can guarantee that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}(W^j)^T$ satisfies the unique tensor property. Don't we need this to conclude that $\exp(W)^T = \exp(W^T)$? I can't see how I can conclude this is the transpose of $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}W^j$ is from the fact that the transpose relation holds for finite sums. And I can replace $(W^T)^j$ by $(-1)^j W^j$, but how do I multiply infinite sums of tensors?

Comment: Infinite polynomials are still just polynomials and you use the distributive property. So you have $\sum a_i \cdot \sum b_j = \sum (a_i\sum b_j)$.  However this problem does *not* require you to do this. All the normal properties of the exponential function still apply like $e^0=I$, $e^Ae^B=e^{A+B}$ and $e^{-A}=(e^A)^{-1}$.The fact that they're tensors is irrelevant as long as you can take powers and add them. Don't overthink it, this is just $e^x$.